# DELETE ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN

Tags: sql

i'm looking for a way to delete records in table 1 with matching combinations in table 2 on 'stn' and 'jaar'. The contents of column 'jaar' in table2 is formatted in a previous stage/query by

> year(datum) AS 'jaar'

Sorry, can't find again the site where i found this "solution".

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE stn, year(datum) IN (SELECT stn, jaar FROM table2);
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Specify it in tags of your question

Comment: That DELETE statement is not valid. When using the `IN` operator the sub-select may not return more than one column. It will generate an error in any sensible DBMS

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve this using `exists`:

```
DELETE
  FROM table1
 WHERE exists(
           SELECT 1
             FROM table2
            WHERE table2.stn = table1.stn
              and table2.jaar = year(table1.datum)
       )
```

Comment: Thank you very much DavidEG! It works! Saved me a lot of time ;-)

Comment: I think I'm getting errors in SQL Server 2012 when I add a shorthand (i.e. `FROM table1 t1`). But I could have a completely different error

Answer (score 15):

The canonical T-SQL (SqlServer) answer is to use a `DELETE` with `JOIN` as such

```
DELETE o
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Customers c
    ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
WHERE c.FirstName = 'sklivvz'
```

This will delete all orders which have a customer with first name Sklivvz.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding parentheses around the row in `table1` e.g.

```
DELETE 
  FROM table1
 WHERE (stn, year(datum)) IN (SELECT stn, jaar FROM table2);
```

The above is Standard SQL-92 code. If that doesn't work, it could be that your SQL product of choice doesn't support it.

Here's another Standard SQL approach that is more widely implemented among vendors e.g. tested on SQL Server 2008:

```
MERGE INTO table1 AS t1
   USING table2 AS s1
      ON t1.stn = s1.stn
         AND s1.jaar = YEAR(t1.datum)
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: The SQL-92 code is rejected by MS SQL 2008 with the error like "Incorrect syntax near ','", which points to the fragment right after WHERE :(

Comment: @AntonK: Yes indeed, "your SQL product of choice doesn't support it." But _you can_ vote for it: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors