# Delete records from table A where field x in Table B = y

Tags: sql, sql-delete, delete-record

I have the following query I have been using and it works well enough for displaying the records I want to delete in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT zen_customers_basket.*
FROM zen_customers_basket, zen_products
WHERE zen_customers_basket.products_id = zen_products.products_id
            AND zen_products.products_availability = 'out of stock'
```

I then check all the records and then delete them. It's fairly quick and painless, but I need a query that will automatically delete these records so I can automate it with some other queries that are scheduled to run once per hour. Any and all help would be appreciated. I know how to delete records but I'm not sure of the proper syntax here since I'm selecting things from two different tables and I don't want to screw anything up.

Comment: Do you want to delete per hour?

Comment: If you're just looking to delete the records that match the SELECT above, why not just use DELETE from with the same WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE zen_customers_basket
FROM zen_customers_basket, zen_products
WHERE zen_customers_basket.products_id =          zen_products.products_id
        AND zen_products.products_availability =    'out of stock'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DELETE FROM Table  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT zen_customers_basket.*
FROM zen_customers_basket, zen_products
WHERE zen_customers_basket.products_id = zen_products.products_id
            AND zen_products.products_availability = 'out of stock')
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019957/delete-from-where-i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019957/delete-from-where-in)n

Answer (score 0):

Delete using same conditions as per your query. Not sure the deleting based on hour. Please clarify.

```
DELETE FROM zen_customers_basket
   INNER JOIN zen_products
   ON zen_customers_basket.products_id = zen_products.products_id
   WHERE zen_products.products_availability = 'out of stock'
```

Reference: [T-SQL: Selecting rows to delete via joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins)